# How to use multiple fetchs with POST, DELETE and then GET requests

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I have a problem with moving one object on the list to another with fetch when `onClick`. Firstly I am doing POST request than DELETE and in the end, I use GET to update the state in React. But it is not working well like the state is not updating. How to solve it?

```
const handleFormAccept = (id: any) => {
        console.log(id);
        fetch(
            `api/forms/${currentUserData.name}/${currentUserData.date}/${currentUserData.email}/${currentUserData.phone}`,
            {
                method: "POST",
            }
        ).then(() =>
            fetch(`api/forms/${id}`, {
                method: "DELETE",
            }).then(() =>
                fetch("api/forms")
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        setFormsData(data);
                    })
            )
        );
    };
```

Comment: Learn about async/await and catch errors.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working please? The code you have should technically work. Two improvements you can make: first, make sure to `return fetch` in all places. It wouldn't change the way the code works right now, but it would just be overall more correct since that way anything waiting on the top-level Promise can wait for the entire chain to complete (you don't show what method calls `handleFormAccept`). Second, it's common in API design for `POST` and `DELETE` requests to return the effected object. If you did that you could remove the final `GET` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `async-await` it is now more readable and easy to understand what you are doing I just console the value can set according to that

```
  const handleFormAccept = async (id: any) => {
    try {
      const postRes = await fetch(
        `api/forms/${currentUserData.name}/${currentUserData.date}/${currentUserData.email}/${currentUserData.phone}`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
        },
      );
      console.log({ postRes });
      const deleteRes = await fetch(`api/forms/${id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
      });
      console.log({ deleteRes });

      const getRes = await fetch('api/forms');
      console.log({ getRes });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: While more readable, simply saying to use async-await will not changing the actual execution of the code, which OP says is not working. Switching to async-await would not change if the code is working as needed or not.